# Workflow and management questions: On-topic?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Just saw this question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/how-to-manage-game-graphics-project and was wondering: Are workflow / management questions (when they relate exclusively to the graphic design field and can have therefore specific requirements) on topic? And if they are, should we create new tags to go with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still adjudicating that particular question. It's not precisely a design issue, but in the real world it's the kind of thing designers and people who work with them do run into. A poorly set up design team can fail miserably, even though the individual designers may be both talented and competent. Legal questions, such as copyright, model releases and "how do I handle my clueless boss?" fall into much the same category of things that profoundly affect a designer's craft, even though they are not directly part of the craft.

Scott has already commented that it seems more a management question than design, and he's right. On the other hand, there's a team of designers out there whose work is about to be made almost impossible.

Comment: That's what I thought. Maybe it's good to keep this range of questions in mind as part of the general debate on how to improve GD's scope and visibility.

Comment: I think the workflow side of that question is fine, but it specifically is a tricky question as a) it's very broad, maybe too broad to answer (I'm sure books have literally been written on the topic, I linked to one that is close), b) not sure how represented computer game graphics currently are here, lots of different workflow issues, c) it's from the point of view of someone whose full time job is management, rather than workflow alongside design work. I think it's an example of an unusually difficult/problematic workflow question.

Answer (score 0):

To me.... It's no different than if someone asked a question about managing an inventory of *whizbang hinges* across 20 different metal fabricators. The actual asset is irrelevant.

The mere fact that the project is related to design doesn't make it a design question in my opinion. It's purely a project management or subordinate management question.

If the **designer** were asking how to manage deliverables when they need to be aware of [legal issues, copyrights, releases] then that may be more of a design question. But a manager asking how to manage the assets being delivered by employees and schedule their project is not a design question.

In reality, he should be having that discussion with the employees - "How long do you feel you'll need to complete XXXX?" Then factor that into the project timeline. So... even if one disagrees with me and feels it is a design question... no one here could possibly answer it without full project specifications, which were not provided.

Comment: I agree, a project related to design isn't necessarily a design question. But we've answered questions like http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/what-are-some-tips-for-a-graphic-designers-cv-resume which are not strictly design either, and they seem to attract more people.

Comment: @yisela I see your link as far more related to design in my opinion. I don't see any comparison between a designer asking how to improve a CV and a manager asking how to organize assets. Apples and oranges to me.